# How to use the callback function in vc++ dll to respond to the click event in the widget UI dll based on Qt?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, dll

When a click event  happens on the Qt based UI dll, how to call the processing function in a VC++ .dll or .exe? (qtwinmigrate` is used in my project). In short, When pushButton is clicked how to call function elementsExampleCreateShapeActive().

This is my QT dll code.

```
//define the callback function pointer
typedef wchar_t const*      WCharCP;
typedef void(CALLBACK *FunCallBack)(WCharCP);

//define the callback function
FunCallBack OnEvent = NULL;
//define the callback function var
int par;
WCharCP unparsed;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetFunCallBack(FunCallBack fun, WCharCP var)
{
    OnEvent =fun;
    unparsed = var;
}

void CDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    OnEvent(unparsed);
}
```

And Below is the code for pulgin dll in VC++.

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *FunCallBack)(WCharCP);
void CALLBACK handleEvent(WCharCP unparsed)
{
    elementsExampleCreateShapeActive(unparsed);
}

void attachLibrary()
{
    char* dllName = "qtdialog.dll";
    HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(dllName);
    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        typedef int(*pMain)(int, char *[]);
        pMain dialog2 = pMain(GetProcAddress(hDLL, "main"));
        if (dialog2 != NULL)
        {
            dialog2(0, 0);
        }
        typedef void (CALLBACK *PFunCallBack)(FunCallBack);
        PFunCallBack SetFunCallBack = (PFunCallBack)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SetFunCallBack");
        if (SetFunCallBack)
        {
            SetFunCallBack(handleEvent);
        }
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot find" << dllName << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `QObject`s on both sides? In this case a signal/slot connection would be the most straightforward solution. If not you need to give more details on the issues you have, including the relevant code.

Comment: This project is about a plugin for a graphic platform named Microstation. I use the QT as the UI tool，create a qt dll, and call it in the main vc++ plugin dll for Microstation. Compile the main vc++ dll need some special tool, so all

Comment: so implement all code in QT is very hard for me now. I don't know how to call the processing function in main vc++ dll when the qt pushbutton is clicked.